# How can I Run 2 Tests Using XML Runner at the same WebDriver?

Tags: java, oop, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm using Selenium with Java WebDriver and with test Runner Suit(XML), I have 2 tests to run.

I have put a setup method in each Test class and it was OK - the tests was working well (each test with its browser window).

Then I decided to move the setup method to the configuration class. This class is extended by each test class, and this creates a problem that the second test run overrides the first by using the same browser.

Setup class method code:

```
public class Configrations_And_ScreenShotsFunc_POM   {

protected WebDriver driver;

    public void setup()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Web Driver\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");    
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
        driver.get(URL);
    }
```

Test 1 class Code:

```
public class TestCase1_POM extends Configrations_And_ScreenShotsFunc_POM   {

@BeforeTest
public void Begain() throws InterruptedException
{
    setup();  //Setup Browser       
}
```

Test 2 class Code:

```
public class TestCase2_POM extends Configrations_And_ScreenShotsFunc_POM   {

@BeforeTest
public void Begain() throws InterruptedException
{
    setup(); //Setup Browser        
}
```

Runner.Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="2" parallel="tests">
    <test name="TestCase1">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Edge" />
        <classes>
            <class name="POM.Tests.TestCa se1_POM"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="TestCase2_POM">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Edge" />
        <classes>
            <class name="POM.Tests.TestCase2_POM"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: The 2 tests files are in a folder, and the configurations class in another folder.

How can it be solved?

Comment: The hole Runner:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="2" parallel="tests" >

<test name="TestCase1">

<parameter name="browser" value="Edge" />

<classes>


<class name="POM.Tests.TestCa
se1_POM">



</class>

</classes>

</test>

<test name="TestCase2_POM">

<parameter name="browser" value="Edge" />

<classes>

<class name="POM.Tests.TestCase2_POM">
</class>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>

Answer (score 0):

Use `@BeforeTest` annotation on your `setup()` method instead of your current `Begin()` and remove your `Begin()`.

Comment: i do this, it stopped to override but still not working 2 tests together.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation `@BeforeTest` is intended to be invoked only once per `<test>` tag in your suite.xml file. Resorting to browser instantiations in a `@BeforeTest` method which is available in a base class from which all test classes extend has the below disadvantage :

- Depending on how the `WebDriver` instance is being saved (either as a static data member or as an instance variable), test methods can either end up using the same WebDriver instance (in the case of static data members) (or) end up getting `NullPointerException` (in the case of instance data members)

You can consider moving the browser instantiation into a much more granular level such as :

- `@BeforeClass` (here also the drawback is there that if there are more than one `@Test` annotated test methods in your class which all use the `WebDriver` instance initialized by your `@BeforeClass`, then during parallel execution you will end up having race conditions amongst your test methods ) or into a
- `@BeforeMethod` annotated method.

I had created a blog post that shows you how to do parallel executions with TestNG without using any of these configuration annotations, inheritance etc., Please see if it helps you.

Blog link : https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/